# Big bitmap not always created

Tags: android, memory, drawing

everybody!

I draw a plot based on some data in my app. The plot is with scrolling and zooming. I create 2 bitmaps for this purpose in MyMainFragment.onActivityCreated().

```
if (bitmaps[0] != null)
      {
         return;
      }    

final int deviceWidth = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
          final int deviceHeight = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
          final int deviceMaxDim = Math.max(deviceHeight, deviceWidth);

          bitmaps[0] = Bitmap.createBitmap(
             deviceMaxDim * 2,
             deviceMaxDim * 1,
             Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

          bitmaps[1] = Bitmap.createBitmap(
           bitmaps[0].getWidth(),
           bitmaps[0].getHeight(),
           bitmaps[0].getConfig());
```

I need 2 bitmaps and not only 1 because of the drawing algorithm I use. Running the program on Asus Transformer, the bmp size in pixels is 1280 * 2 * 1280, thus the byte size being 1280 * 2 * 1280 * 4. When I run the program from Eclipse, everything's fine. But when I launch it like an ordinary user from the tablet, it crashes every second time.

What's happening behind the scene when I launch my app from Eclipse that allows it to run and can I follow the same steps programmatically so that it doesn't crash when launched normally? Or should I use some other drawing algorithms (maybe something like OpenGL)?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=10821 could be helpful.

Comment: Thanks a lot, stacker! That looks quite close to my situation, though android version is 4.0.3 on my device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was simple. I created a Canvas somewhere in my code, called Canvas#setBitmap(bitmaps[?]) on it, but didn't realise, that I must call Canvas.setBitmap(null) to free the reference.